# Delete an action from the NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 views with 3 controllers: `HomeView -> LoginView -> AccountView`
In `HomeView` I added a `NavigationBarController`. When the user logs in in the `LoginView`, he is moved to the `AccountView`. When He clicks on the back button in the `NavigationBar`, he is sent to the `LoginView` and this is the problem. After logging if the user clicks on the back button, I want to show him the `HomeView` and not the `LoginView`. I tried this code but it takes some time to be executed and I can see the `LoginView` for some milliseconds.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {   
    if let token = userDefaults.valueForKey("token") { //User logged in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: First you need to check your storyboard connected segue because some where you are connected seque with ibaction and you also calling it by suing  `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the viewDidApper in the AccountView, you can delete the LoginView from the ViewControllers stack this way

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(1)
```

this way, if user will go back, he/she will see the home page as requested

Answer (score 0):

If login is success, why don't you just use

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```